# How to hide the Design/Split/Source bar in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2015

Is there is a way to hide the Design/Split/Source bar in HTML (Web Forms) Editor?

(Visual Studio 2015)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Web Forms Designer**, and uncheck **Enable Web Forms designer (requires restart of Visual Studio)**

[image: Please refer to this screen capture]

2. Restart Visual Studio

By doing this, "Design" and "Split" tabs will be removed.

If you want to remove the whole bar, you can go to **Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** > **File Extension**, and add a mapping for **aspx** extension to **HTML Editor**. IntelliSense for server controls will not work.

Comment: I did this but the bar did not disappear.

Comment: After mapping aspx extension to HTML Editor, .aspx file has to be closed and reopened. Then the bar will disappear